# List Orders NewEgg API

Tags: xml, rest, api, soap

I checked the NewEgg API reference documentation but cannot find how to list orders by token or particular id like Ebay and Amazon provide in their APIs.
Amazon has ListOrders which fetches details for a particular merchant id. Similarly, I need to list orders for New Egg as well but cannot find something that can help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Get Order Info section of the Order Management API.
https://mkpl.newegg.com/wiki/doku.php/api_developer_guide:order_management#get_order_info

Example JSON Request:

```
PUT https://api.newegg.com/marketplace/ordermgmt/order/orderinfo?sellerid={sellerid}
Authorization: {authorization}
SecretKey: {secretkey}
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
{
  "OperationType": "GetOrderInfoRequest",
  "RequestBody": {
      "PageIndex": "1",
      "PageSize": "10",
      "RequestCriteria": {
          "Status": "0",
          "Type": "0",
          "OrderDateFrom": "2011-01-01 09:30:47",
          "OrderDateTo": "2011-12-17 09:30:47",
          "OrderDownloaded": 0,
          "CountryCode":"USA",
          "PremierOrder":"0"
      }
  }
}
```

Or the report management section of the API.

https://mkpl.newegg.com/wiki/doku.php/api_developer_guide:reports_management#order_list_report

An example JSON request:

```
POST https://api.newegg.com/marketplace/reportmgmt/report/submitrequest?sellerid={sellerid}
Authorization: {authorization}
SecretKey: {secretkey}
Content-Type: application/json
Accept: application/json
{
  "OperationType": "OrderListReportRequest",
  "RequestBody": {
    "OrderReportCriteria": {
      "RequestType": "ORDER_LIST_REPORT",
      "KeywordsType": "0",
      "Status": "0",
      "Type": "0",
      "OrderDateFrom": "2018-01-01",
      "OrderDateTo": "2012-01-31",
      "OrderDownloaded": "false",
      "CountryCode":”USA",
      "PremierOrder":"0"
    }
  }
}
```